# En python mi codigo no elimina los 'todos' con el checkbox

Tags: python, checkbox, eliminar

Estoy haciendo una tarea de programación, el programa es para hacer una lista de tareas por hacer (To-dos) o pendientes.

Estoy usando una libreria de python que nos esta ensenando el profesor, la cual sirve para generar una pagina web, la libreria se llama **Streamlit**

Las cuales se agregan mediante un campo de input, el **todo** queda guardado en un archivo de texto, ademas  cada 'todo' tiene un checkbox y al dar click en un checkbox debe eliminar ese 'todo'. Tanto de la vista como del archivo de texto.

Este es mi codigo:

```
todosWeb.py

import streamlit as st
import functions

todos = functions.get_todos()


def add_todo():
    todo = st.session_state["new_todo"] + '\n'
    todos.append(todo)
    functions.write_todos(todos)
    st.session_state["new_todo"] = ""


st.title("Mi App de Tareas")
st.subheader("Bienvenido a la App de Tareas")
st.write("Esta app esta hecha para ayudar a tener una mejor")
st.write("organizacion con tus actividades, tareas y/o pendientes")

for index, todo in enumerate(todos):

    # Genera una clave unica para cada checkbox
    key = functions.numero_random()

    checkbox = st.checkbox(todo, key=key)
    print(checkbox)
    if checkbox:
        todos_pop = todos.pop(index)
        del st.session_state[todo]
        st.session_state.sync()

st.text_input(label='Escribe tu pendiente', label_visibility="hidden",
              placeholder='Escribe una tarea...', on_change=add_todo,
              key='new_todo')
```

functions.py

```
import random


FILEPATH = "todos.txt"


def get_todos(filepath=FILEPATH):
    # Default parameter
    """
        Read a text file and return the list
        of todos items.
    """
    with open(filepath, 'r') as file_local:
        todos_local = file_local.readlines()
    return todos_local


def write_todos(todos_arg, filepath=FILEPATH):
    # los default parameter deben
    # ir despues de los no default parameter.
    """Write the todo items list in a file text."""
    with open(filepath, 'w') as file:
        file.writelines(todos_arg)


def numero_random():
    numero_r = random.random()
    numero_r = numero_r * 10
    return numero_r
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero una observación, ten mucho cuidado con cosas como:

```
    for index, todo in enumerate(todos):
        ...
        todos_pop = todos.pop(index)
```

Nunca debes modificar la longitud de un iterable (agregar o eliminar items) mientras iteras sobre el con un iterador, eso invalida automáticamente el iterador y ocasiona errores o comportamientos indeterminados. La única excepción es que rompas el ciclo inmediatamente (si el lenguaje te permite siquiera que modifique el iterable y no genera una excepcion).

Si necesitas eliminar elementos, hay varias opciones dependiendo del caso, como iterar sobre una copia, generar un nuevo iterable con los cambios y reemplazar el original con este, iterar usando indexado pero en orden inverso para evitar generar indices inválidos, etc.

Dicho esto, el problema principal de tu codigo se debe a como generas las claves de tus checks y como funciona streamlit:

- Cada vez que el usuario interactua con la app modificando algo, se produce inmediatamente una ejecucion completa de tu script. La excepcion son las callbacks, que son ejecutadas antes de reejecutar el script.
- Generas las claves de tus widgets aleatoriamente, por lo que cada vez que se ejecuta el script se generan nuevas keys y nuevos widgets que no estan asociados con los de ejecuciones previas.

Estas dos cosas se unen para que pase lo siguiente:

1. Tu App inicia, ejecuta el script `todosWeb.py`, genera los CheckBoxs necesarios a partir del txt (o el usuario ingresa los que quiere). Una clave aleatoria se genera para cada CheckBox que es usada para identificar el widget.
2. El usuario marca un CheckBox.
3. **Inmediatamente tu script `todosWeb.py` es ejecutado de nuevo**.
4. Se generan los checkboxs a partir del archivo como en el punto 1, pero las claves serán diferentes a las de la ejecución anterior al ser aleatorias.
   Esto hace que el estado check de tus anteriores CheckBoxs no sea tenido en cuenta, porque de facto estos widgets son otros widgets con sus propias keys y que como es obvio están desmarcados por defecto.
5. Como ningún CheckBox esta marcado, nada se elimina.

Si tu lista de TODOs no admitiera duplicados (que una misma tarea aparezca repetida varias veces), la solucion seria muy simple:

```
# todosWeb.py

import streamlit as st
import functions


todos = functions.get_todos()

def add_todo():
    if (todo:= f"{st.session_state['new_todo']}\n") not in todos:
        todos.append(todo)
        functions.write_todos(todos)
    else:
        st.toast("¡Ya existe esa tarea en la lista!")
    st.session_state["new_todo"] = ""

st.title("Mi App de Tareas")
st.subheader("Bienvenido a la App de Tareas")
st.write("Esta app esta hecha para ayudar a tener una mejor")
st.write("organizacion con tus actividades, tareas y/o pendientes")

for index, todo in enumerate(todos):
    checkbox = st.checkbox(todo)
    if checkbox:
        del todos[index]
        functions.write_todos(todos)
        st.rerun()
        break # No seria necesario porque st.rerun() reinicia la ejecucion

st.text_input(label='Escribe tu pendiente', label_visibility="hidden",
              placeholder='Escribe una tarea...', on_change=add_todo,
              key='new_todo')
```

O usando una callback:

```
# todosWeb.py

import streamlit as st
import functions


todos = functions.get_todos()

def add_todo():
    if (todo:= f"{st.session_state['new_todo']}\n") not in todos:
        todos.append(todo)
        functions.write_todos(todos)
    else:
        st.toast("¡Ya existe esa tarea en la lista!")
    st.session_state["new_todo"] = ""
    
def on_check(todo_index):
    del todos[todo_index]
    functions.write_todos(todos)

st.title("Mi App de Tareas")
st.subheader("Bienvenido a la App de Tareas")
st.write("Esta app esta hecha para ayudar a tener una mejor")
st.write("organizacion con tus actividades, tareas y/o pendientes")

for index, todo in enumerate(todos):
    checkbox = st.checkbox(todo, on_change=on_check, args=(index,))

st.text_input(label='Escribe tu pendiente', label_visibility="hidden",
              placeholder='Escribe una tarea...', on_change=add_todo,
              key='new_todo')
```

En ambos casos no se permite agregar un TODO que ya exista en la lista, en cuyo caso aparece un toast avisando al usuario de que ya existe esa tarea en la lista.

Si quieres permitir duplicados (checkbox con el mismo texto), necesitas generar tu la clave. Para solventar el problema de comentado arriba, una opción obvia es guardar la clave de cada checkbox en el txt junto a su texto texto, de forma que la clave seria la misma para cada ejecución. No obstante, si esa es toda tu app, puedes hacer algo muy simple, usar el indice de cada TODO como clave y usar una callback para evitar el problema comentado al principio:

```
# todosWeb.py

import streamlit as st
import functions


todos = functions.get_todos()

def add_todo():
    todos.append(f"{st.session_state['new_todo']}\n")
    functions.write_todos(todos)
    st.session_state['new_todo'] = ""
    
def on_check(todo_index):
    del todos[todo_index]
    functions.write_todos(todos)

st.title("Mi App de Tareas")
st.subheader("Bienvenido a la App de Tareas")
st.write("Esta app esta hecha para ayudar a tener una mejor")
st.write("organizacion con tus actividades, tareas y/o pendientes")

for index, todo in enumerate(todos):
    checkbox = st.checkbox(todo, key=f"{todo}{index}", on_change=on_check, args=(index,))

st.text_input(label='Escribe tu pendiente', label_visibility="hidden",
              placeholder='Escribe una tarea...', on_change=add_todo,
              key='new_todo')
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, esta muy buena la respuesta, ni si quiera conocía el operando walrus.